# Error ubuntu apt-get update

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

When i try to apt-get update its giving me this error

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource 
temporarily 
unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

First of all, i'm root on the system

What i tried?

1. Rebooting the server
2. sudo dpkg --configure -a
3. sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.lis /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list

Any solution?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites  http://askubuntu.com OR  http://superuser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Try sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf 
sudo apt-get update

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/739274/ignore-all-dependencies-for-a-specific-package-with-apt-get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock` file and force package reconfiguration.

```
sudo rm  /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This should work.

You can also try:
You can delete the lock file with the following command:

```
sudo rm  /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

You may also need to delete the lock file in the cache directory

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm  /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

After that, try opening Synaptic again.

**Do the following**

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
```

After that reinstall it

Search for Programs and Updates Change Download from: Main server On the Other Programs tab Activate Caninical Partners and leave all others disabled Update system Then add your PPAs one by one and update if problems are disabled, if there are no problems leave it enabled Finally in terminal: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: Hey dude, thanks for the response. the error disappear now but there is another error now. here is a screenshot : http://prntscr.com/f85t82

Comment: I will update my answer

Comment: Thanks again but for both sudo apt-get install -f and sudo apt-get update .. There is this output : http://prntscr.com/f85yln

Comment: Search for Programs and Updates
Change Download from: Main server
On the Other Programs tab
Activate Caninical Partners and leave all others disabled
Update system
Then add your PPAs one by one and update if problems are disabled, if there are no problems leave it enabled
Finally in terminal: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Answer (score 1):

The resource is temporarily unavailable, that's the problem. Ubuntu automatically checks for updates once the system boots up, the best way is to wait for a few minutes while it searches for updates then run your update command.

Another possibility is to search for a process running the apt-get command.

```
ps -A | grep apt-get
```

Kill that process with the command:

```
sudo kill -9 <process-id>
```